# VS Code occasionally auto-updates my Typescript import paths

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, filepath, tsconfig

I've implemented some path shortening in my Angular project so that the paths in my import statements would not look like this:

```
import { ReserveComponent } from '../../../../../libs/ui/reservations/reserve.component'
```

Instead, they now look like this (much nicer, I'd say)

```
import { ReserveComponent } from '@libs/ui/reservations/reserve.component'
```

The detailed steps are provided here, on [AngularFirebase](https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/shorten-typescript-imports-in-an-angular-project/).

Following the tutorial, I've set up my `tsconfig.ts` like this:

```
 "paths": {
      "@libs/*": ["libs/*"],
      "@libs/business/*": ["libs/business/src/*"],
      "@libs/ui/*": ["libs/ui/src/*"],
      ...
    }
```

Everything works great. **The problem is that every so often, VSCode decides to update all my import paths by putting *`src`* in the path!** Like this:

```
import { ReserveComponent } from '@libs/ui/src/reservations/reserve.component'
```

This breaks the imports. I have no idea why VSCode decides to do this and I cannot tie it to any specific action on my part. It just seems to do it at random times.

I'd appreaciate any tips or advice anyone can offer

Comment: What version of VS Code are you using?